# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘tensorflow’ in anaconda python 3.6.3

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, anaconda

i use Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit) ubuntu 16.04 64 bits.
I installed tensorflow. I did the following steps:

1. conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.6
2. source activate tensorflow
3. pip install –ignore-installed –upgrade \ https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.5.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

I have an import error of tensorflow:

ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)

in ()
—-> 1 import tensorflow as tf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘tensorflow’

How to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you use anaconda, it's usually better to use the conda installer if possible.

```
source activate tensorflow
conda install tensorflow
```

it will display something like:

```
Fetching package metadata .......
Solving package specifications: ..........

Package plan for installation in environment 
/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

backports:              1.0-py36_0          
backports.weakref:      1.0rc1-py36_0       
bleach:                 1.5.0-py36_0        
html5lib:               0.9999999-py36_0    
libprotobuf:            3.4.0-0             
markdown:               2.6.9-py36_0        
mkl:                    2017.0.3-0          
numpy:                  1.13.1-py36_0       
protobuf:               3.4.0-py36_0        
six:                    1.10.0-py36_0       
tensorflow:             1.3.0-0             
tensorflow-base:        1.3.0-py36h5293eaa_1
tensorflow-tensorboard: 0.1.5-py36_0        
werkzeug:               0.12.2-py36_0       

 Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]
```

then, you should be able to successfully import tensorflow

```
(tensorflow) user@ubuntu: $ python

Python 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:51:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>>
```